# Alterar a escala do eixo X

Tags: r, plot

Olá, estou tentando fazer um gráfico de afilamento do tronco de uma árvore, onde o eixo y é a altura (metros) e o eixo x é o diâmetro (cm). Até aí sem problemas, porém gostaria de mudar a escala do eixo x para dar mais realismo e não estou conseguindo fazer isso, alguém teria alguma sugestão ?

Comment: O que você chama de mudar a escala do eixo x, transformar de cm para metros por exemplo?

Answer (score 6):

Se tu estiver usando os comandos básicos do R para fazer o gráfico (`plot()`), tu pode mudar o eixo x/y com o parâmetro `xlim`/`ylim`

```
x <- rnorm(100, 10, 2)
y <- rnorm(100, 100, 20)
plot(x, y)
plot(x, y, xlim = c(0, 120)) # Alterando somente o eixo X
plot(x, y, ylim = c(0, 120)) # Alterando somente o eixo Y
plot(x, y, xlim = c(0, 120), ylim = c(0, 120)) # Alterando os 2 eixos
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, mas eu havia tentado fazer isso.. Até faz o que eu quero o problema é que o eixo x ou y, fica demasiadamente extenso e sem utilidade no espaço vazio..

Comment: @MarcoMachado O que você quer então? Edite a sua pergunta para deixar o problema mais claro se esta não é a solução que você está procurando.

Answer (score 1):

Eu segui [esse tutorial](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html), que mostra como configurar os eixos de uma maneira bem didática.

Mas em resumo, explicando com minhas palavras e da forma que usei no meu caso (sou iniciante no R), eu fiz assim:

```
# axes=F -> retira os eixos do seu gráfico.
plot("seus dados", ..., axes=F)

# A função axis permite configurar os eixos, sendo "1"
# indicativo do eixo "abaixo" do gráfico (o eixo "x")
# e o parâmetro "at" indica que valores devem aparecer
# no eixo. Da mesma forma para o eixo vertical.
axis(1,at=c(x1,x2,x3,...,xn)

# "2" indica o eixo y (à esquerda do gráfico)
# e pelo "at" seus respectivos valores.
axis(2,at=c(y1,y2,y2,...,yn))
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!